# How do i set an array of an expandable size to prevent null pointer exception?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

The aim is to retrieve data from a MYSQL table and input this into a list view. In order to do this I am putting the values into an array. However, it seems that the length of the array must be equal to the number of values taken from the table (which can vary); or the app will respond with a null pointer exception.

My question is: How do i set the arrays to be dynamic in length so the error does not evolve? Or is there an alternate way?

**Defining the arrays used:**

```
       public String titleId[] = new String[2]; //Defining the arrays used
       public Integer imageId[] = new Integer[2];
```

**Setting the Arrays equal to the values:** (Currently, this will perform 2 iterations)

```
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

       titleId[i] = "test";
       imageId[i] = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

   }
```

**Using arrays to set up ListView:**

```
          CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(getActivity(), data.titleId, data.imageId);      
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**CustomList.java (Used to set up custom adapter)**

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] titleId;
private final Integer[] imageId;

public CustomList(Activity context,
String[] titleId, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.single_row, titleId);
this.context = context;
this.titleId = titleId;
this.imageId = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    txtTitle.setText(titleId[position]);

    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `ArrayList` instead of `Array`

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){` should be `for(int i=0; i<titleId.length();i++){`, since I can't see any jArray array definition with length = 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use dynamic data structures provided by the JDK. To be more concrete, those implementing the `List` interface seem to match your goal.

You should gather your data in a  `List` object and later you can generate an array from it.

For example:

```
List<String>  titleId = new ArrayList();
```

Lets suppose you are getting your data from a JDBC result set:

```
while(res.next())
{
    titleId.add(res.getString("dbTableColumn"));
}
```

Finally, you generate an array from the list and pass it to `CustomList` constructor:

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), data.titleId.toArray(), ...);
```

Comment: Since ArrayLists cannot be used directly, how would i then edit my CustomList.java file, which is used to create the Custom Adapter. I have updated the question.

Comment: @jamesgates1 I don't understand your comment. Do you mean you cant use `ArrayList` in your program at all? Neither `LinkedList`?

Comment: No, I meant that CustomList.java will not accept an ArrayList. It will only accept an Array. It works fine in the other parts of the program.

Comment: @jamesgates1 that is why I wrote you have to use `toArray()` method. It will return an array with the same contents of the list. Please check my answer last line.